# FLUTTER DIO API DATA ONLY SHOWING PROGRESS DIALOG AND DOES NOT DISPLAY ANY DATA ON SCREEN

Tags: flutter, api, dio

I have been struggling to show api data on screen, I tried everything, please guys may you please help me out.I did all my best and still, I get a blank screen, I tried different methods and solutions and still. please check my code below. The screen only shows a circular progress dialog all the time. The data is being fetched and showing on the console, I am just struggling to make it appear on UI screen.

My model class

```
class Autogenerated {
  int? id;
  int? sourceId;
  int? serviceId;
  int? categoryId;
  String? category;
  String? description;
  int? serviceResponsePropertyId;
  int? mappingId;
  bool? isVisible;
  int? packageRequestId;
  int? sortOrder;
  Value? value;

  Autogenerated(
      {this.id,
      this.sourceId,
      this.serviceId,
      this.categoryId,
      this.category,
      this.description,
      this.serviceResponsePropertyId,
      this.mappingId,
      this.isVisible,
      this.packageRequestId,
      this.sortOrder,
      this.value});

  Autogenerated.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    sourceId = json['SourceId'];
    serviceId = json['ServiceId'];
    categoryId = json['CategoryId'];
    category = json['Category'];
    description = json['Description'];
    serviceResponsePropertyId = json['ServiceResponsePropertyId'];
    mappingId = json['MappingId'];
    isVisible = json['IsVisible'];
    packageRequestId = json['PackageRequestId'];
    sortOrder = json['SortOrder'];
    value = json['Value'] != null ? new Value.fromJson(json['Value']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['SourceId'] = this.sourceId;
    data['ServiceId'] = this.serviceId;
    data['CategoryId'] = this.categoryId;
    data['Category'] = this.category;
    data['Description'] = this.description;
    data['ServiceResponsePropertyId'] = this.serviceResponsePropertyId;
    data['MappingId'] = this.mappingId;
    data['IsVisible'] = this.isVisible;
    data['PackageRequestId'] = this.packageRequestId;
    data['SortOrder'] = this.sortOrder;
    if (this.value != null) {
      data['Value'] = this.value!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Value {
  String? make;
  String? type;
  String? model;
  int? year;
  String? body;
  String? driveType;
  String? fueType;

  Value(
      {this.make,
      this.type,
      this.model,
      this.year,
      this.body,
      this.driveType,
      this.fueType});

  Value.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    make = json['make'];
    type = json['type'];
    model = json['model'];
    year = json['year'];
    body = json['body'];
    driveType = json['drive_type'];
    fueType = json['fue_type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['make'] = this.make;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['model'] = this.model;
    data['year'] = this.year;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    data['drive_type'] = this.driveType;
    data['fue_type'] = this.fueType;
    return data;
  }
}
```

My JSON data

```
[
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "AdjustedValues",
        "Value": [],
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 474,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 475,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "CarId",
        "Value": 120354,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 100,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Year",
        "Value": 2017,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 103,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 6
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Full Model Description",
        "Value": "2017 AUDI A3 Sedan 1.0T FSI S tronic [2016-2017]",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 104,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Model",
        "Value": "A3 Sedan 1.0T FSI S tronic [2016-2017]",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 105,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 5
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ImageUrl",
        "Value": "https://cdn.lightstoneauto.co.za/PHOTOS/AUDI/120354_1_Z7.jpg",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 107,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Make",
        "Value": "AUDI",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 110,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Type",
        "Value": "AUDI A3 Sedan",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 111,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 4
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 6,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 125,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 126,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "SpecCategory": "General",
        "Id": -1,
        "SourceId": -1,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Body shape",
        "Value": "Sedan",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 320,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "SpecCategory": "General",
        "Id": -6,
        "SourceId": -6,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Drive type",
        "Value": "4x2",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 154,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "CarId": 0,
        "SpecCategory": "General",
        "Id": -7,
        "SourceId": -7,
        "ServiceId": 7,
        "CategoryId": 1,
        "Category": "General",
        "Description": "Fuel type",
        "Value": "Petrol",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 153,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 9999
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "LastFiveSales",
        "Value": [
            {
                "SaleId": 698229,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-06-09T15:30:38Z",
                "SalePrice": 299900.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "CITY OF TSHWANE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 695530,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-05-30T13:24:17Z",
                "SalePrice": 289995.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "CITY OF TSHWANE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 685020,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-04-14T12:27:37Z",
                "SalePrice": 366948.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "EMFULENI",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 683843,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-04-11T15:00:38Z",
                "SalePrice": 315500.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "UMHLATHUZE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "SaleId": 652718,
                "CarId": 120354,
                "SaleYear": 2017,
                "SaleDateTime": "2022-04-01T11:53:45Z",
                "SalePrice": 339900.0,
                "MunicipalityName": "CITY OF TSHWANE",
                "Id": 0,
                "SourceId": 0,
                "ServiceId": 0,
                "CategoryId": 0,
                "Category": null,
                "Description": null,
                "Value": null,
                "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
                "MappingId": 1,
                "IsVisible": false,
                "PackageRequestId": 0,
                "SortOrder": 0
            }
        ],
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 481,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "ServiceStatus",
        "Value": {
            "StatusCode": 1,
            "StatusDescription": "Ok",
            "StatusDetail": "",
            "RestServiceStatus": null,
            "ServiceResource": null
        },
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 482,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Auction",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 1,
        "SourceId": 1,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Auction Estimate",
        "Value": 189400.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 494,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Cost",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 2,
        "SourceId": 2,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Cost Estimate",
        "Value": 238300.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 495,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Cost",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 3,
        "SourceId": 3,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Cost Estimate High",
        "Value": 259800.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 496,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Cost",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 4,
        "SourceId": 4,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Cost Estimate Low",
        "Value": 218700.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 497,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 2
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Retail",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 5,
        "SourceId": 5,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Retail Estimate",
        "Value": 300800.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 498,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Retail",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 6,
        "SourceId": 6,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Retail Estimate High",
        "Value": 327900.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 499,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Retail",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 7,
        "SourceId": 7,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Retail Estimate Low",
        "Value": 276000.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 500,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 2
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Trade",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 8,
        "SourceId": 8,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Trade Estimate",
        "Value": 261300.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 501,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 1
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Trade",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 9,
        "SourceId": 9,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Trade Estimate High",
        "Value": 284900.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 502,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 3
    },
    {
        "EstimateType": "Trade",
        "CarId": 0,
        "Id": 10,
        "SourceId": 10,
        "ServiceId": 12,
        "CategoryId": 5,
        "Category": "Valuation",
        "Description": "Trade Estimate Low",
        "Value": 239800.0,
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 503,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": true,
        "PackageRequestId": 13818024,
        "SortOrder": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 7,
        "Category": "Report",
        "Description": "ReportUrl",
        "Value": "https://pdf.lightstoneauto.co.za/Index.aspx?sourceurl=https://cdn.lightstoneauto.co.za/REPORTS/LIVE/ba22673b-0f05-4ae9-b212-0369a7c793ad.html",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 0,
        "SortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": 0,
        "SourceId": 0,
        "ServiceId": 11,
        "CategoryId": 7,
        "Category": "Report",
        "Description": "HtmlUrl",
        "Value": "https://cdn.lightstoneauto.co.za/REPORTS/LIVE/ba22673b-0f05-4ae9-b212-0369a7c793ad.html",
        "ServiceResponsePropertyId": 0,
        "MappingId": 0,
        "IsVisible": false,
        "PackageRequestId": 0,
        "SortOrder": 0
    }
]
```

My API call

```
 Future<Welcome?> signInData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = prefs.getString('token');

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post('$_baseUrl/api/gateway',
          data: {
            "ClientPackageId": "0cdd231a-d7ad-4a68-a934-d373affb5100",
            "PlatformId": "ios",
            "ClientUserId": "AhmedOmar",
            "VinNumber": VINumber
          },
          options: Options(headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
          }));
      print("data is here");
      print(response.data.toString());
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Welcome.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data.toString()));
      }
      else if (response.statusCode == 500) {
        // call your refresh token api here and save it in shared preference
        print(response.statusCode);
        await getToken();
        signInData();
      }


    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

  }
```

A class where I want to show my data on UI

```
class ResultsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResultsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ResultsPageState createState() => _ResultsPageState();
}

class _ResultsPageState extends State<ResultsPage> {
  Future<Autogenerated?>? objectList;
  _APIState? api;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    objectList = api?.signInData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            //centerTitle: true,
            ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Autogenerated?>(
            future: objectList,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data!.value?.make ?? ''),
                  ]),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I am only displaying "Value". Please guys I really need help with this. Thanks

Comment: @Ravindra S. Patil can you please assist

Comment: can u tell me the error that shows while running this?

Comment: Hi @Kokila it shows no error, just shows circular progress dialog